# Sweep quest for thieves guild in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm wondering if I've run into a bug on the Xbox version of Skyrim.  I have a sweep quest for Vex in the Thieves' Guild to clear Bolli's house in Riften of three valuables.  I've scoured the house and only 2 high value items have appeared.

I've gotten the items from the side table on the first floor and the item on the stand at the end of the bed upstairs.  Not sure where #3 spawns.

I've opened every searchable container in the house and no other high value item is present.

Does this happen often or am I just missing something, like the other spawn point?

Comment: Where does your quest pointer point to?

Comment: Bolli's house when I look at the city view of my maps.  I'll have to check tonight while in his house where it points to.

Comment: There was one sweep job I did where one of the items had apparently fallen off of a dresser (long before I got there, so I didn't knock it over!); in my case it was clearly visible on the floor in front of it, but I've seen items all but disappear behind furniture before, or even clip right through the floor! See if you can't wiggle your way around furniture enough to peek behind it.

Comment: @PirateEric Your compass should show you where the quest item is when you are in the same area/building as the item.  When you get close, the pointer should appear in your main display - even through walls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did get it completed, the other piece was ontop of the wardrobe upstairs.  It never seemed to spawn there.  I'll see if I get the same thing happening in other sweep quests.

Answer (score -3):

That happens often: you need to reload to a earlier save a start again.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can always abandon the quest by talking to Vex, and ask for a new one.